# How does unbound handle multiple forwarders (forward-addr)?

Tags: domain-name-system, forwarding, unbound

According to https://nlnetlabs.nl/documentation/unbound/unbound.conf/ multiple forwarders can be configured with `forward-addr`

> For the forward zone this list of nameservers is used to forward the
> queries to. The  servers  listed  as forward-host:  and  forward-addr:
> have to handle further recursion for the query.

However there is no statement how these servers are used. Is only the first server queried? Are all simultaniously queried and fastes answer will be sent? Or are they queried in a round robin style? Or another option?

Answer (score 1):

Well I couldn't find a better source, but it seems that it uses the first address and then if it is not responsive after certain time, it takes the next in the list.

I found [this page](https://lists.nlnetlabs.nl/pipermail/unbound-users/2018-January/005055.html) that seems to be a conversation with someone from support.

It also says that some other load balancer algorithms are not available.

Answer (score 0):

Unbound's SRTT implements RFC2988
https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2988.

Basically unbound will occasionally select randomly a server whose SRTT is between the fastest and (fastest + 400ms).

Bind similarly uses a decaying function on the srtt so that it will occasionally pick a slower server instead of just sticking with the fastest one.